# what happen when parent process and child process read the same file and write to the other same file?

Tags: linux, unix

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int fdrd,fdwt;
char c;
void rdwrt();
main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    if(argc!=3)
        exit(1);
    if((fdrd=open(argv[1],O_RDONLY))==-1)
        exit(1);
    if((fdwt=creat(argv[2],0666))==01)
        exit(1);
    fork();
    rdwrt();
    exit(0);
}
void rdwrt()
{
    for(;;)
    {
        if(read(fdrd,&c,1)!=1)
            return;
        write(fdwt,&c,1);
    }
}
```

**This program forks a child process,then parent process and child process try to read the same input file and write to the same output file.**

Excute this program like this:

```
[root@localhost]./a.out input output
```

where content of input file is:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

**I thought the output file should have equal number of characters to the input file,though the character order probably not the same according to the competition of these two processes.**

It turns out that the output file is:

```
abcdefghijklmnonqbcdefghijklwxyczdefjklpqrstuvwxyz
abcefgklmvwxefgklmnopqrstuvw
qrstuyz
abcdhijxyz
```

**Actually,these tow files have different characters number**:

```
[root@localhost]wc -m input output
162 input
98  output
```

**Now I wonder why?**

Comment: I was drawn back here by a recent comment ... This question is much more interesting than I first realized three years ago, because predicting its operation requires understanding a subtle point in the unix fork model. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The contents of the output file will be difficult to predict because your program contains a [*race condition*.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) Specifically, it depends on process scheduling.

*Requested update:*

This question is actually more interesting than it looked at first glance.

I'm going to make some predictions *(tested successfully...)*

On Unix-like systems<sup>1</sup> ... then, **yes**, the number of characters will always be the same but the order will be difficult to predict.

You tagged your question <kbd>linux</kbd> <kbd>unix</kbd>, and in those systems, all of which<sup>1</sup> properly implement the fork model, both children will share a single file position for both (forked) instances of `fdrd`, and they will share a second file position for both instances of `fdwr`.

If you could slow down time and watch the program run, at any point there are things you know and things you don't.

You don't know which child will win the race to do the next read, but you *do* know which character the winner will read, because they are always at the same file position. After the winner gets that next character, you still don't know who will read the following one, because the race is still on.

In fact, it is possible that the same process will win the race again, and again, because the scheduler probably won't want to run it for a very small time slice.

At any moment you also know that the next character will be written at EOF because, again, *shared write position.*

Now, you might ask, well then, if both processes are always at both the same input and output file positions, how does the file get cracked up?

Well, there is more than one race, one to the read and a second to the write. (Or one, kinda complicated race.) One child may have read its character but not written it when it gets time-sliced. So now it starts losing the race *to the write statement* and then probably to several iterations of read/write. So a character can get hung up in one child.

And finally, on merely-API-compatible C environments running over other operating systems, anything could happen. The OP's system appears to be one of these, or perhaps the test was flawed. My OSX system behaves as predicted.

---

<sup>1.  "Real" UNIX, *BSD, OSX, or Linux.</sup>

Comment: I know,but I think the characters number of these two files should be euqal,because every read system call will be followed by a write system call in this program.Right?

Comment: Actually zhen lee is correct on the character count, but not because of the paired read/write statements, as there are still races.  See my updated answer.